# Associating two tables that both belong to a third, independent table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, database-design, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three tables:

```
Topics        Jobs          Requests
-----         ----          --------
title         description   request
description   worker_id     user_id   
              topic_id      worker_id
                            topic_id
```

Workers create a job for each Topic. Users can then request the worker to do that job.

My current associations:

```
class Topic < AR::Base
  has_many :jobs
  has_many :worker, through: :jobs
end

class Job < AR::Base
  belongs_to :topic
  belongs_to :worker
  has_many :requests
end

class Request < AR::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :worker
  belongs_to :topic
  has_one: :job, through: :topic   #This doesn't work, lol.
end
```

The problem:

I'm not sure if a Request should belong to a Topic, or a Job.

I need to:

- access a request's topic info more often than the job info, but still have the job info available.
- create a request based on the topic and worker, not the job. (This is important.)
- list all requests for a given topic.
- preload topic and job info for requests. (Also important.)

I'm hesitant to directly associate Requests and Jobs because Jobs contains some info that should not be available to all requests. With that association any request could access that info, but maybe that's not a huge deal.

Also, because I need such a close association between Requests and Topics, it seems more logical to go with that association, but then I lose easy Job access. (With the above associations I have to use a custom method: `Job.find_by(topic_id: self.topic_id, worker_id: self.worker_id)` which doesn't allow for preloading or multiple requests.)

What's the best way to go here?

(Let me know if there's a better title.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Topic always belongs to Job, Request should belong to Job and only Job. You can always traverse the association to Topic. This makes sense logically, because users request that a worker do a job. The topic is just additional information about that job. If a user requested a topic, how would you know what job they wanted done?

On an additional note, because the worker is attached to the job (no worker would ever do a job they did not create), that worker_id should only be on the Job model, not the Request model.

Switch your tables to this, and you should be good:

```
Topics        Jobs          Requests
-----         ----          --------
title         description   request
description   worker_id     user_id   
              topic_id      job_id
```

Comment: Yes, that's true. Users request jobs not topics, so I guess that's my answer. Technically, I could still find the job through the topic_id and worker_id - it just wouldn't be a proper association. If I remove the worker_id from requests, how can I find all the requests for a worker? Through jobs? Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's true about finding the job through topic_id, I missed that. To get all the requests for a worker would be trickier, but doable best with a has_many :through association. A worker has many requests through jobs. This way you can just reference Worker.first.requests.load to get all of the first worker's requests, for example.

Comment: That makes sense. If I were to find the job for a request by topic/worker ids how would that association work, if at all? Just want to make sure I understand both options. Appreciate it.

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you have the request, you find the job by the job_id. If all you have is a worker_id and a topic_id, you can run the Ruby method select for Job.all.select{ |job| job.worker_id == some_worker_id && job.topic_id == some_topic_id }. This gets you all jobs with the worker and topic ids that you are checking against. Does that address your question?

Comment: If my answer worked for you, would you be so kind as to upvote and select it? That's the bit of cheese for us mice. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, sorry! Totally meant to, then forgot. Appreciate the help! Edit: can't upvote, but I accepted it.